# How to automake C source files

Tags: c, makefile, autoconf, automake, linkage

I have a file cmdscan.c that contains just a function and a struct. My main program hsh.c uses the function and struct from cmdscan.c. I followed the instructions on my professor's pdf exactly but it will not work. Even if I edit something save and run make it says there is nothing to be done. And when I use make distcheck I get an error saying it can't find hsh.c.

This is what my directory contains:

**Makefile.am:**

```
    bin_PROGRAMS = hsh
    hsh_SOURCES = hsh.c cmdscan.c
```

**configure.in:**

```
    AC_INIT(hsh.c)
    AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(hsh,1.0)
    AC_PROG_CC
    AC_PROG_INSTALL
    AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

I made sure to use tabs.
Then I run the commands:

```
aclocal
autoconf
touch README AUTHORS NEWS ChangeLog
automake -a
configure
make
```

Note: when I run "configure" it says command not found. But I can run ./configure so that's what I did.

When I do last command "make" I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Even if I edit something and save it. So when I run

```
make distcheck
```

I get:

```
configure: error: cannot find sources (hsh.c) in ..
make: *** [distcheck] Error 1
```

If I run:

```
gcc cmdscan.c hsh.c -o hsh
```

It works.

Comment: What documentation are you reading that recommends the name `configure.in`?  It is *very* old.

Comment: I just followed the instructions he gave in the pdf for the assignment. I emailed him but he hasn't replied.

Comment: And putting the package name and version in `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` instead of `AC_INIT` is even more obsolete!

Comment: Seriously, your instructors documentation is about 10 years out of date.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, IIRC it's more like 12+ years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors like:

```
AC_INIT(hsh.c), AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(hsh,1.0) instead use for example:
AC_INIT([hsh],[1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.14])
```

where "1.14" is my automake version, you can see this: automake --version

If you need a quick tutorial see: http://embelinux.blogspot.de/2013/09/autotools1-hola-mundo-la-autotools.html
If you need strong documentation run: apt-get install autoconf (see /usr/share/doc/autoconf-doc)
and download http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.pdf‎

```
AC_INIT (package, version, [bug-report], [tarname], [url])
```

Process any command-line arguments and perform initialization and verification.
    Set the name of the package and its version. These are typically used in ‘--version’
    support, including that of configure. The optional argument bug-report should be
    the email to which users should send bug reports. The package tarname differs from
    package: the latter designates the full package name (e.g., ‘GNU Autoconf’), while
    the former is meant for distribution tar ball names (e.g., ‘autoconf’). It defaults to
    package with ‘GNU ’ stripped, lower-cased, and all characters other than alphanumerics
    and underscores are changed to ‘-’. If provided, url should be the home page for the
    package.
    The arguments of AC_INIT must be static, i.e., there should not be any shell compu-
    tation, quotes, or newlines, but they can be computed by M4. This is because the
    package information strings are expanded at M4 time into several contexts, and must
    give the same text at shell time whether used in single-quoted strings, double-quoted
    strings, quoted here-documents, or unquoted here-documents. It is permissible to use
    m4_esyscmd or m4_esyscmd_s for computing a version string that changes with every
    commit to a version control system (in fact, Autoconf does just that, for all builds of
    the development tree made between releases).

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([OPTIONS])
```

Runs many macros required for proper operation of the generated Makefiles.
    Today, AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is called with a single argument: a space-separated
    list of Automake options that should be applied to every Makefile.am in the
    tree. The effect is as if each option were listed in AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS (see
    Chapter 17 [Options], page 117).
    This macro can also be called in another, deprecated form: AM_INIT_
    AUTOMAKE(PACKAGE, VERSION, [NO-DEFINE]). In this form, there are two
    required arguments: the package and the version number. This usage is
    mostly obsolete because the package and version can be obtained from
    Autoconf’s AC_INIT macro. However, differently from what happens for
    AC_INIT invocations, this AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE invocation supports shell
    variables’ expansions in the PACKAGE and VERSION arguments, and this can be
    still be useful in some selected situations. Our hope is that future Autoconf
    versions will improve their support for package versions defined dynamically
    at configure runtime; when (and if) this happens, support for the two-args
    AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE invocation will likely be removed from Automake.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I had to change configure.in to configure.ac. Then I had to add another parameter to my open file statements, `0666`. After that all seems to be well and it compiles and allows me to create a package. The pdf gave no such information -_-.